# Nested End points with angular resource and server nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, rest, express, resources

I have a resource /cars and the endpoint in angular defined as

$resource('/cars/:carsId');

to GET all cars and a specific car.

At the server level, I have also added a middle-ware to check that carsId is always a valid MongoID.

Now I want to define another endpoint to GET all redcars.

My initial though was to add another resource like

$resource('/cars/redcars');

but this does not work since at the server level, my middle-ware will through an error because redcars is not valid MongoID.

My question is what is the best approach in this case ?

I can add a logic at server to check if the MongoID is invalid, but, if the value is redcars then return all redcars.

or there is a better way of doing this.

Thanks

pkpk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical patterns are:

1. use query parameters, as in, /cars/search?color=red
2. use /cars/types where the /cars/types/:color can be applied

An excellent resource for design patterns in API design is the [Apigee API guide](https://pages.apigee.com/rs/apigee/images/api-design-ebook-2012-03.pdf).  **NOTE**: I am **not** endorsing Apigee by recommending their guide; I simply find that this ebook has many useful patterns collected in one place.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for